How do I generate .proto file with placeholder field names from protobuf file?
I'm trying to reverse engineering a protobuf file. The plan is to feed the result of protoc --decode_raw and a list of possible field names to an LLM and instruct it to output a possible proto file.
Having a .proto file with placeholder field names with the correct structure can improve the accuracy of model output, How do I generate .proto file with placeholder field names from protobuf file?

Not easily. You can't even tell whether two sub-messages are of the same type or of different types. There just isn't enough information to extract "the correct structure".
